# Ruby on Rails - Creating rows in an html.erb table by looping over instance variable

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, html-table, erb

I have an instance variable @referrals which contains names of referrals a person has done. I now need to create a table showing all these referrals as rows. I have tried the following code in the html.erb file:

```
<table style="border:1px solid black;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
      <th> Referral Emails </th>
      <% @referrals.each do |referrals| %>
        <tr> referrals </tr>
     <%end %>
</table>
```

and

```
<table style="border:1px solid black;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
      <th> Referral Emails </th>
      <% @referrals.each do |referrals| %>
        <%= <tr> referrals </tr> %>
     <%end %>
</table>
```

Both show up errors.

I am new with Ruby, help with the correct Ruby code is much appreciated. Thanks a ton in advance.

Edits: Code changes as suggested by @mu is too short.

Comment: 2) Code error.
3) Can you point me to the correct ruby code please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default in ERB, code blocks are enclosed in `<%` and `%>` delimiters, and if you want the result of the code block run, you use the `=` symbol inside, like `<%= 'Hel' + 'lo' %>, world` would output "Hello, world".

Each member being iterated over with `.each` is named between the pipe symbols, so that is what you reference inside the block.

Also table rows need to have table data, or `<td>` tags within the row `<tr>` tags.

Here's what should work for you assuming that `@referrals` is a list of strings:

```
<table style="border:1px solid black;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
  <tr> <th> Referral Emails </th> </tr>
  <% @referrals.each do |referral| %>
    <tr> <td> <%= referral %> </td> </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```